# dns issue on newly created kubernetes cluster

Tags: dns, kubernetes

I created a cluster with 2 vm's. I followed instructions listed below.This is on RHEL 7.3
This is after kubernetes was installed using yum.
The version of kubernetes is 1.7

## commands on Master01-only

```
sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1
sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables=1
systemctl stop firewall
systemctl disable firewall
systemctl status firewall
systemctl start iptables.service
systemctl enable iptables.service
iptables -F
service kubelet restart
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr 10.244.0.0/16
```

### make sure you copy the kubeadm join command that gets displayes after cluster creation"

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
kubectl get nodes
kubectl describe nodes
cd ~/Downloads
kubectl apply -f flannel.yml
kubectl apply -f flannel-rbac.yml
kubectl create -f rolebinding.yml
kubectl create -f role.yml
```

## commands on node-only

```
sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1
sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables=1
systemctl stop firewall
systemctl disable firewall
systemctl status firewall
systemctl start iptables.service
systemctl enable iptables.service
iptables -F
kubeadm join --token xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx x.x.x.x:6443
```

The issue i am having is that the dns is not working as expected.
Have been struggling with this for past two days. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Is the KubeDNS addon running?

You should see something like this in your `kube-system` namespace when you list pods:

[image: kube-system namespace pod listing]

If you don't see those pods, try installing the addon: https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/deploy-addons.html

Comment: This is what i have

Comment: kube-system   kube-dns-2425271678-8wdrv                            3/3       Running   0          1h

Comment: i tried the dns addons as well, but it really didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Check firewalld on the nodes...  I have to leave mine off (cause they aren't configured properly).  And if someone randomly turns it back on I have DNS issues with my cluster.